# Трагический конец жизни пакетов

Tags: обсуждение, 1-апреля

Мы знаем, что всякий пакет имеет число `lifetime`, иначе время жизни. Если пакет не доходит до получателя, а это поле достигает нуля, то он исчезает. Но ничего в этой вселенной не пропадает бесследно, где все те пакеты, которые так и не прошли свой путь? Есть ли шанс, что они когда-нибуть восстанут из своих могил и интеренет упадёт от масштабной ddos атаки?

Comment: А за счет чего по вашему работает интернет в раю ? Он работает именно на этих пакетах. Учитывая, что вестей от туда еще никогда не поступало крайне мало вероятно, что эти пакеты вернутся обратно, тем более, что им там должно быть хорошо

Comment: Шанс всегда есть. Хакнет кто-нибудь все роутеры и наступит судный день.

Comment: @Mike, а чего не ответом?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В [RFC 5984 "об увеличении пропускной способности IP-сетей с передачей на базе ЭСВ"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5984) описывается принципиальное устройство сети, выдающую в ряде случаев **нулевую или даже отрицательную задержку передачи**.

Так что эти пакеты, по всей видимости, кем-то всё же принимаются посредством сети этого типа, просто вы не обнаруживаете последствий этого, поскольку **пакет приходит в прошлое или наоборот, в будущее** (приём в будущем в RFC не описывается, но особенности технологии и ограниченное число совместимых устройств в прошлом делают такие случаи неизбежными), **а вы ошибочно ищете последствия в настоящем или ближайшем будущем**.

То есть, **нет, DDoS таким способом малореален**, т. к. вы имеете дело с условной бесконечностью принимающих устройств, причём для каждой передачи [почти наверняка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5) принимать данные будет более новое устройство с куда большими характеристиками, чем у вашего.

---

*Я всё ещё не понимаю, каким образом авторы вышеозначенного RFC сумели установить, что данные были переданы в прошлое, а также насколько им должно было для этого повезти. Впрочем, при работе с такими технологиями приходится отказываться от массы предположений, возможно, я просто ещё к этому не готов.*

*В частности, я делаю (возможно ошибочное) предположение о том, что пакеты будут обязательно приняты в той же вселенной, в которой были отправлены, а потому в условно бесконечном будущем устройств несравнимо больше, чем их существовало до настоящего момента. Если же на деле возможна отправка пакета в любую точку мультивселенной, вероятности становятся куда интереснее.*

Answer (score 4):

Поискав по теме, обнаружил информацию, что любой отправленный и неотправленный пакет можно найти в `/dev/urandom`.

p.s.: приятным бонусом можно получить бесплатную копию "Войны и мира".

Comment: Агась, подозреваю, что аналогичным механизмом хранения данных пользуется упомянутый в RFC 5984 "Null Device", занимающийся приёмом пакетов c ЭСВ-канала. Это объясняет, почему операции чтения из него такие долгие.